# JavaFX-packaged application has no icon in MacOSX 'Application' folder

Tags: java, macos, javafx, icons, finder

I have a Java application packaged by JavaFX packager on a MacOSX 10.6; After installation, I have a nice icon in finder bar, but not in the "Applications" folder, there the icon is like in "construction".

=> How can I change the icon in the "Applications" folder ?
=> Is it a special "icns" format, which could be supported to display the application icon while launched, but not supported for the "Application" folder ?

Thanks for any help...

My build.xml file:

```
<taskdef resource="com/sun/javafx/tools/ant/antlib.xml"
         uri="javafx:com.sun.javafx.tools.ant"
         classpath=".:${java.home}/../lib/ant-javafx.jar" />


<property name="bin" value="my_private_bin"/>
<property name="main.class" value="my.private.MainClass"/>
<property name="application.title" value="my_private_title"/>
<property name="application.vendor" value="my_private_vendor"/>
<property name="application.version" value="1.0.0"/>


<target name="clean">
    <delete dir="target/package-jar"/>
    <delete dir="target/package-deploy"/>
</target>

<target name="jar">
    <fx:jar destfile="target/package-jar/my_app.jar">
        <fx:application mainClass="${main.class}" name ="${bin}"/>
        <fx:resources>
            <fx:fileset dir="target/libs/" includes="*.jar"/>
            <fx:fileset dir="${java.home}/lib/ext/" includes="sunpkcs11.jar"/>
        </fx:resources>

        <fx:platform javafx="2.1+">
            <property name="user.language" value="fr"/>
            <property name="user.country" value="CH"/>
        </fx:platform>

        <fileset dir="target/classes/"/>

        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Implementation-Vendor" value="${application.vendor}"/>
            <attribute name="Implementation-Version" value="${application.version}"/>
        </manifest>
    </fx:jar>
</target>

<target name="deploy">
    <fx:deploy nativeBundles="all" verbose="true" outdir="target/package-deploy" outfile="${bin}">
        <fx:info title="${application.title}" vendor="${application.vendor}"/>
        <fx:application name="${application.title}" mainClass="${main.class}"/>
        <fx:resources>
            <fx:fileset dir="target/package-jar" includes="*.jar"/>
            <fx:fileset dir="target/libs/" includes="*.jar"/>
            <fx:fileset dir="${java.home}/lib/ext/" includes="sunpkcs11.jar"/>
        </fx:resources>
    </fx:deploy>
</target>
```

I also have a 'package' folder with:

- package/macosx/Info.plist
- package/macosx/MyApp.icns
- package/macosx/MyApp-background.png
- package/macosx/MyApp-volume.icns
- package/windows/MyApp.ico
- package/windows/MyApp-setup-icon.bmp

Comment: can you post your 'build.xml' ?

Comment: Yep, just added build.xml content and 'package' folder content.

Comment: For the installer image to work, it must have **exactly the same name as the application**. Please verify this and let me know.

Comment: The problem I have concern the image in the "Applications" folder, which is like an icon "under construction", not the icon embedded. I think that in the "Applications" folder, MyApp.icns should be taken, but it is not the cas. I doubt that the icon display well on MacOSX 10.9, but do not display on MacOSX 10.6. Is it possible ?